# MySQL Workbench 6.1 - Table Editor utf8 characters not being displayed correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL workbench 6.1 and I have this table using a utf8 collation, however when I view it on the editor it looks like this:

[image: mysql workbench image 1]

It **looks ok on the browser**, like below, but I want to see exactly that on the editor too:

[image: mysql workbench image 2]

And **if I change it manually** to how I want it to look like right there on the editor it looks like this on the browser:

[image: mysql workbench image 3]

Comment: Give us your table definition and the code you used to generate the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the charset specification on my php code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```